# Camera issue with coordination with objects

Tags: animation

When ever I make any setup of solar system and lock the camera at few points as to animate it after I reach to the last planet my camera view of previous planets and texts get disturbed. Camera locked at few points get disturbed or the object moves automatically. Please help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender Stackexchange. Please read http://blender.stackexchange.com/help and especially http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question.

Comment: Your question is quite vague. Please use the [edit] link under your question and add more information. Add images that show your settings for the camera and any other information that might help us understand what the problem is.